# If $f(x)=x^2+3x$ and $g(x)=x^2-4x$, solve $gf(x)=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is as follows:

> $f(x)=x^2+3x$ and $g(x)=x^2-4x$. Solve $gf(x)=0$.

I have already substituted to get $(x^2+3x)^2-4(x^2+3x)=0$ which when expanded and simplified, becomes: $$x^4+6x^3+5x^2-12x=0$$

How do I go forward from here to get the values of $x$?

**Edits**
Relevant examples:
[image]

Comment: $g(x)=0$ has two easy to find roots. $g(f(x))=0$ iff $f(x)$ equals one of those roots.

Comment: at least $x=0$ and $x=1$ are solutions...

Comment: @Surb You are correct, 0 and 1 are solutions. However, since there are 4 unknowns in the simplified equation, I think that there are 4 solutions in this question.

Comment: Adding a bit to the first hint given, $g(x)$ is zero implies $x = 0$ or $x=4$. So you only have to solve $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) = 4$, each of those with (potentially) two solutions, giving you the four possibilities.

Comment: $x^2-3x=t$. This is a quadratic and note $t=x^2-3x$ is a common factor.

Comment: @AnilCh When I inputted $4$ into the calculator to create $(4)^4+6(4)^3+5(4)^2-12(4)$,  I got $672$. Thankfully, once I inputted $-4$ instead, I got $0$ (so it is a solution.) But there is one more solution for me to find, which I'm trying to work out at the moment.

Comment: I'm not saying $4$ is a solution of $g(f(x)) = 0$. I'm saying that we know two things. First, $g(z) = 0$ happens only if $z = 0$ or $z = 4$. Second, we are interested in $g(f(x)) = 0$, so (substitute $z$ by $f(x)$ in the previous statement) this implies $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = 4$. Two solutions from $x^2+3x = 0$ and two other solutions from $x^2+3x=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a common factor.
$$(x^2+3x)(x^2+3x -4) = 0 $$
The product is zero if at least one term is zero.

Comment: Note: this factorisation falls out if you factor $g(x)$ first, before substituting $f(x)$ in for $x$. That is, if we note that $g(x) = x(x - 4)$, then $g(f(x)) = f(x)(f(x) - 4) = (x^2 + 3x)(x^2 + 3x - 4)$.

Answer (score 2):

As per what Surb have given you, that x=0 and x=1 are solutions of the polynomials, g(f(x)) = x(x-1)h(x). So your goal here is to find h(x) which can be done using long division. Thereafter, you would be able to find the roots of the polynomial g(f(x)).

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by getting $h(x)$ by using long division. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Long division here basically means that you take g(f(x))/(x(x-1)) = h(x). You can check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division for reference.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).